# Rounded Corners On Image With Object-Fit: Contain

Tags: css

Is it possible to have rounded corners on an image which has the CSS-property "object-fit: contain" and where the image width is smaller than the container width?

I have created the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0g9azyb6/.

```css
.container {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: .5rem;
}

img {
  background-color:#444;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-grow: 1;
  object-fit: contain;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #222;
}

.footer {
  border-radius: .3rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://krolop-gerst.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/20210618-LUMIX-S-50-F1.8-an-DC-S5-1-640-Sek.-bei-f-18-50-mm-ISO-160-NASENLOeCHER-2.jpg">
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

But the width of the image is always the same width as the container.

[image: Expected Result]

(This should work on Chrome and Safari.)

Comment: not possible with object-fit, you need a different idea

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Added a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the use of object-fit and width then rely on `margin: auto;` to center the image.

```css
.container {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: .5rem;
}

img {
  background-color:#444;
  border-radius: .3rem;
  height: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #222;
}

.footer {
  border-radius: .3rem;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://krolop-gerst.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/20210618-LUMIX-S-50-F1.8-an-DC-S5-1-640-Sek.-bei-f-18-50-mm-ISO-160-NASENLOeCHER-2.jpg">
  <div class="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with landscape images: https://jsfiddle.net/yj0vm156/1/

Comment: @Yoolan you didn't specify this into your requirement but we can make it works with any image: https://jsfiddle.net/r1k4hsm8/